# Override a function without extending the class

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class A:

```
public class A {
    public A(){....}
    public void method1() {...}
};
```

And an instance of that class:

```
A anA = new A();
```

Is there any way to override the `method1()` only for `anA`?
This question arises when I write a small painting program in which I have to extend the `JPanel` class several times just to make minor changes to the different panels that have slightly different characteristics.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
A anA = new A() {
    public void method1() {
        ...
    }
};
```

This is the same as:

```
private static class myA extends A {
    public void method1() {
        ...
    }
}

A anA = new myA();
```

Only with the exception that in this case `myA` can be reused. That's not possible with anonymous classes.

Comment: True, however technically this is creating an anonymous class that extends the class A.

Answer (score 17):

You can create a an new anonymous class on the fly, as long as you are using the no-arg constructor of your class `A`:

```
A anA = new A() {

  @Override
  public void method1() {
    ...
  }
};
```

Note that what you want to do is very close to what is known as a *lambda*, which should come along the next release 8 of Java SE.

Answer (score 3):

I like to do this kind of thing with a delegate, or "strategy pattern".

```
public interface ADelegate {
   public void method1();
}

public class A {
    public A(){....}
    public ADelegate delegate;
    public final void method1() { delegate.method1(); }
};

A anA = new A();
anA.delegate = new ADelegate() {
   public void method1() { ... }
};
```